# Синхронность выполнения программы

Tags: c#, события

Есть следующая логика работы:

```
private state state;
OnStateChanged += controller;

private void FirstListener()
{
    //Какая-то работа
    state = First;
    StateChanged();
}



private void SecondListener()
{
    //Какая-то работа
    state = Second;
    StateChanged();
}

private void StateChanged()
{
    if (OnStateChanged != null)
        OnStateChanged();
}

private void controller()
{
    switch (state)
    {
        case first:
            //Вызов метода1;
            break;
        case second:
            //Вызов метода2;
            break; 
    }
}


private void FirstEvent()
{
    //Произошло событие 1
    FirstListener();
}

private void SecondEvent()
{
    //Произошло событие 1
    SecondListener();
}
```

Происходит следующее: обработчики событий `FirstEvent` и `SecondEvent` получили известие о событии. Первым, чуть раньше, его получил `FirstEvent` , вторым — `SecondEvent`. События разные и друг с другом не связаны. 
Правильно ли я понимаю, что: сначала отработает метод `FirstListener` (обновит значение переменной состояния и поставит в очередь потока задание на выполнение обработки события `OnStateChanged`), затем отработает `SecondListener`, сделает тоже самое, что и `FirstListener`. После этого отработает подписчик на изменение состояния - controller, где перейдет в обработку по значению `second` (так как второй обработчик обновил значения переменной `state`), а после `controller` отработает еще раз, сделав тоже самое. Прав ли я в понимании синхронности?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите. События посылаются синхронно. Что это значит? Что обработчики вызываются в момент изменения.

Пусть например вызвался `FirstListener` Он установит `state` в `First` и вызовет `StateChanged()`, который внутри себя вызовет `OnStateChanged()`, который есть по сути вызов `controller()`. То есть `controller()` отработает *во время* выполнения `FirstListener`. Вот стек выполнения:

```
FirstListener начался
    state = First;
    StateChanged начался
        controller начался
            switch (state) // state = First
            //Вызов метода1;
        controller окончился
    StateChanged окончился (если других подписчиков нет)
FirstListener окончился
```

После этого точно так же отрабатывает `SecondListener`.

Comment: Спасибо большое! то есть SecondListener будет ждать, пока выполнится FirstListener ? После этого он гарантированно выполнится? А если потом должен будет отработать thirdListener, он также станет в очередь? Если это так, то нет ли возможности очистить эту ожидающую очередь, если firstlistener уже начал обработку?

Comment: @Sleeeper: нет, немного не так. Пока вызывается event `FirstEvent` и выполняется `FirstListener`, event `SecondEvent` вовсе не может быть отправлен, потому что поток-то занят выполнением кода `FirstListener`. А вот когда `FirstListener` отработает, лишь тогда сможет произойти `SecondEvent`. Никакой очереди нет.

Comment: То есть пока поток занят, никакой обработчик внутри класса, где поток выполняется, не будет отвечать на события(как на свои внутренние, так и на внешние) ? А когда поток освободится, то только тогда станет возможной отработка, но уже новых событий, а не тех, что не смогли обработаться, так как поток был занят?

Comment: @Sleeeper: Вы всё ещё почему-то думаете, что события в потоке происходят «сами по себе», вне зависимости от того, что делает поток. Пока поток занят, события не могут никак в нём «возникнуть». Код, который отправляет событие, точно так же бежит в том же потоке, и в принципе никак не может получить управление, пока поток занят. Пока поток занят, события принципиально не могут возникнуть.

Comment: Это я понимаю. Однако есть и события, которые работают(дергаются) и определены в другом потоке(совсем другой код), на которые осуществляется подписка внутри данного псевдокода. FirstEvent и SecondEvent - обработчики событий, которые(события) инициируются совсем в другом месте и работают также в другом потоке. Подписка на них происходит в рамках указанного кода. Отсюда и вопрос: если поток занят, однако подписка на события другого потока осуществлена, что будет происходить? Будет осуществлен пропуск обработки, так как поток занят или же будет создаваться очередь?

Comment: ответом но мой вопрос может быть Ваш ответ на мой другой, смежный вопрос: "Хуже того, если пока работает обработчик события, этот поток блокируется, и доставка всех других событий приостанавливается." Верно ли это для того случая, который я указал в комментарии выше?

Comment: @Sleeeper: Стоооооп! Если событие возникает в _другом_ потоке, то оно выполняется синхронно в другом потоке. Опять-таки никто никого не ждёт, и если события произошли почти одновременно в разных потоках, то и обработчики будут выполняться параллельно в разных потоках.

Comment: То есть даже если обработчик события инициирован в одном потоке(и подписан на него), а само событие происходит в другом, то обработчик будет выполняться в том потоке, где произошло событие(там же событие и объявлено)?

Comment: @Sleeeper: Что такое «инициирован»? В любом случае, да, обработчики события выполняются в том потоке, где произошло событие, вне всякой зависимости от того, где была произведена подписка на событие. Я ж говорю, события по сути ничем не отличаются от простого вызова функции.

Comment: Допустим: есть некий класс Y, где существует событие RainStart. В обеъкте x, который был создан в другом потоке и на текущий момент занят(например while-ом) была осуществлена подписка на событие RainStart класса Y. Метод подписчик в классе x на событие RainStart класса Y будет выполнен в потоке, где работает код класса Y? Даже в случае, если поток, в котором работает обработчик в классе X, блокирован длительной процедурой?

Comment: @Sleeeper: Метод-подписчик будет вызван в том потоке, где произойдёт событие `RainStart`. Если гипотетически одновременно одно и то же события произойдёт в двух разных потоках, метод-обработчик будет бежать одновременно в этих потоках.

Comment: Спасибо большое, разложили все по полочкам. Очень Вам благодарен.

Comment: @Sleeeper: Пожалуйста! Рад, что разобрались. Event'ы — очень важная тема.

Comment: Согласен, тема наиважнейшая. У меня есть событие, которое очень часто происходит. И определено оно в отличном от обработчика месте и потоке. Данный обработчик вызывает изменение перехода посредством установки значения перехода и "дергания" события StateChanged . На больших объемах данных стек переполнялся(на StateChanged ). И только теперь мне стало понятно, сто обработчик отрабатывал каждый раз, когда происходило событие и происходило переполнение. Да уж, печально.

Answer (score 1):

Если `OnStateChanged` - это обычный C#-овый event - то нет, не правильно. (кстати обычно называют наоборот - событие `StateChanged`, а метод который его триггерит внутри класса - `OnStateChanged`).

Для обычных event никакой "очереди потока задание на выполнение обработки события". События - это, приближенно говоря, просто набор подписанных на него методов. Т.е. код:

```
if (OnStateChanged != null)
    OnStateChanged();
```

просто выполняет все методы всех объектов, которые в данный момент на событие подписаны. Т.е. в вашем случае он отработает как обычный прямой вызов:

```
private void StateChanged()
{
    controller();
}
```

Comment: по поводу именования события и метода - прошу прощения, опечатался.

Comment: @Sleeeper суть ответа - не в том, как назвать метод. а в том, что события в C# - это обычный вызов метода (или методов), который на событие подписан. А не какая-то хитрая система с очередями, блокировками, очередями в потоках, пропусками обработки и прочим, что вы упоминаете в комментариях. Ничего этого просто нет.

Comment: Вероятно я действительно усложнил схему работы событий у себя в голове..